# why do i am getting Failed to create deployment error while deploying my website on github pages

Tags: html, github, deployment, github-pages, github-for-windows

I created a html website. I uploaded all the source code in my GitHub repository. Now I want to host my website using GitHub Pages but I am getting Error that says:   'Failed to create deployment (status: 500) with build version 35c4d9bf78f338ba8319cfe032e967dd258d9ede. Server error, is githubstatus.com reporting a Pages outage? Please re-run the deployment at a later time'

[This is the error which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a3hK.png)

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by several reasons, just re-run the deploy job after some minutes. For me, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub Actions to deploy the code on every push:

Make sure you enabled the Build and deployment Source of "GitHub Actions"

Settings -> Pages section -> Build and deployment -> Source: GitHub Actions